# WebView Client Not Allowing to Open SAPUI5 Projects with MVC, But opens on Browser(SAPUI5)

Tags: android, android-webview, sapui5, webviewclient

I am unable to get a WebView to load an URL(Containing SAPUI5 Resources and hosted on Github Pages). The URL is a Public URL and loads perfectly in the browser.(Also loads in the Android Chrome Browser).

But, when i put it in a Web View Client it goes blank screen.
The URL is: https://thesourav123.github.io/souravtestpage/

But, when i put it in a plain WebView(**Without Client**), it opens up in the Phone's browser and loads correctly.

**Reason**
The folder structure is the primary reason for this issue. If i put everything in index.html then it loads fine.(With the same error log) But, if i keep my views and controller in separate places, it doesn't load. But, then i won't be able to do any MVC Coding which will affect me in the long run.

The GitHub Source code for the URL(Which is not loaded):
https://github.com/thesourav123/souravtestpage

As mentioned above, If i put everything in index.html,it works, the example for this is https://github.com/thesourav123/souravtestpage2
and URL is https://thesourav123.github.io/souravtestpage2/

```
The Error Log Data:

    W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
    W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
    I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
    D/AppTracker: App Event: start
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    D/AbstractTracker: Event success
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
    I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
    W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10004

The Code is as follows:

       mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Set WebView client
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        String url = "https://thesourav123.github.io/souravtestpage";
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
private void openWeb(String url) {
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Progress = " + progress);
                if (progress != 100) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                }
                if (progress == 100) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Loading finished");
                }
            }
        });
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Alejandro. Not Working. In this case, i am getting the same output in Log. Although, the Progress Dialog keeps on running.
 D/TAG: Progress = 10
 D/TAG: Progress = 20
 W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5046
 D/TAG: Progress = 100
 D/TAG: Loading finished
 D/TAG: Progress = 100
 D/TAG: Loading finished

Comment: Hi @SouravDas Are you sure the url contains a working website? Then you can find in log "Loading finished" message, right? I say that because the native WebView sometimes is slowyle (it can take until a minute).

Comment: @Alejandro, if you click on the link in my question it will take you to the actual page.
I found the issue. It is with the folder structure and the Web View Client. I am updating the question now to make it more clear.